# How should I design a struct in cpp?

Tags: c++, oop

I've got the following struct:

```
struct Point {
   double x, y;
   std::string name;
   vector<vector<double>> matrix;
}
```

I know all but the last property `matrix` from the start and in order to compute `matrix` I have to know some other objects.

However I'd like to keep `matrix` in `Point` struct. Since there's no `point_id` or sth like that that will allow me to create a map.

Is it a good style just to use `(x, y, name)` constructor and then explicitly set `matrix` later on in the code.

Comment: Representing a matrix with a vector of vectors might be a bad idea (because the subvectors should all have the same size). Maybe you should design your own  `Matrix`  class as some abstract data type

Comment: To reduce the amount of padding needed to allign members of the struct, order them from largest alignment requirement first to smallest alignment requirement last.

Comment: Without an  [MCVE], and without some detailed motivation, **your question is very unclear**, and probably matter of opinion so off-topic here. What exactly is your `Point`  and `matrix`  for? We cannot guess that!

Answer (score 5):

> Is it a good style just to use (x, y, name) constructor and then explicitly set matrix later on in the code.

Yes that's fine, create your matrix with no elements and perhaps set it's capacity if you have any idea of it's final size.

Answer (score 2):

> However I'd like to keep matrix in Point struct. Since there's no point_id or sth like that that will allow me to create a map.

Misconception about standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). They don't require any kind of "id", and maps only need a compare operation on the type of their key.

Remember that [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) can be used with an *explicit* `Compare`  argument. You might provide one which just compares the `x, y`  and/or the `name`  field. For example:

```
struct mycompare_st {
   inline bool operator() (const Point& x, const Point& y) {
     return x.name < y.name;
};
```

and later use `std::map<Point, Matrix, mycompare_st>` after having defined an appropriate `Matrix`  class.

Likewise [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) also accepts a compare function, and [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) may be given an equality operation and an hashing operation, and there are cases where it is worthwhile to do so.

BTW, I don't think that representing a matrix as a vector of vectors is a good idea (since every column of a matrix has the same size, by definition of matrices). I would recommend making your own `Matrix` class (or abstract data type).

> Is it a good style just to use (x, y, name) constructor and then explicitly set matrix later on in the code.

Coding style is really a matter of opinion, but what you suggest doing is usual practice.

You could also use some kind of [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) for your matrix. Read about the [`<memory>`  standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Perhaps have your `Point`  could contain some 
`std::unique_ptr<Matrix> matrixptr;` field ?